# How to get the top level container of a JComponent?

Tags: java, swing

Is there a way to get the top level container of a component? For example I have a JToolbar and I want to know at one monent the top level container of that JToolbar is my JFrame or is its own window, a JDialog.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(...);
```

Answer (score 6):

If the component has been added to the hierarchy, you can look up the top-level container by recursively calling `getParent`:

```
Container c = toolbar;
while ( c.getParent() != null )
{
  c = c.getParent();
}

if ( c instanceof JFrame )
{
  //...
}
```

Comment: Today I faced this same problem and did exactly the recurive method and worked fine.
Actually the approved answer won't work if the container of the component is a JPanel.
So I believe that the second answer is more flexible cause it let's you choose what to look for....