# Opening a file with default application and bringing said application to foreground

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

### How to bring the default application for a file extension to the foreground after opening said file?

#### Context

The task to solve is opening a file from a Java Swing application with the default program assigned to the file extension. These files include videos, audio files as well as 3D model files. It can be expected that users have software on their machines installed to open such files, however it is not known what software this is going to be, *e.g.* some may open STL files with the default viewer provided by Win10, some may open those using Blender and so on.

The larger context is to provide users with helpful resources and grant access to those resources directly from the application.

#### Problem

Implementing this functionality worked out well. Users are given UI components showing them lists of available resources. They then select a resource and that resource is opened. If the default application of the respective file extension was not open up to this point, then it will open and be put into foreground by Windows. However if it was already open, then it will remain in the background and users may not notice that something happened due to this fact.

---

An example:

1. Users select a `.mp4` file in the Java application.
2. Opening the file using the default Windows selection for the file extension `.mp4` is triggered by the Java application
3. This default program happens to be VLC, which was previously closed, now opens and is put into foreground by Windows
4. User watches the video and wants to watch a different one
5. To do so, the Java application is maximized again and the user clicks on a different `.mp4` selection in the Java Swing UI
6. The video immediately starts playing in VLC. However VLC remained open and thus is no longer put into foreground by Windows

--> The user does not see any effect and may expect something broke.

#### What have I tried?

First of all, I tried opening the file using the `Desktop` object as well via `Runtime`:

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open( file );
```

vs.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "cmd /c start " + file );
```

Both of these exhibited the same behavior with regard to window priority. A different idea was putting the Java application into background upon opening a resource. The approaches described here have been tried:

[How to get the top level container of a JComponent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660943/how-to-get-the-top-level-container-of-a-jcomponent)

```
SwingUtilities.windowForComponent( panel );
```

and

```
Container c = toolbar;
while ( c.getParent() != null )
{
  c = c.getParent();
}

if ( c instanceof JFrame )
{
  //...
}
```

But this is not possible either. Firstly, the parent element is an object inheriting from `JDialog` rather than a `JFrame` and secondly the Java application is in a state, where the Windows function "minimize" is not available - it can only be closed or kept as is. Only if the dialog was to be closed, this would unlock minimization.

Possibly the UI could be reworked to allow for that, but this approach does not seem *pretty* either. Users may not want to minimize the Java application and besides, a different application may still be in front of the default application for the file extension of the file to be opened.

Lastly I was thinking about implementing containers for all these file formats in the Java application and showing those in a `JFrame`. This is not viable either. Not only does the effort explode when trying to implement a custom viewer for all possible resource file formats, but additionally our users are likely to be using specialized software for specific extensions and they will want to view these resources in that software, rather than in a viewer of our Java application.

---

While the issue of the default application for a file extension staying in the background is rather minor it is still annoying to me. Can I somehow resolve this issue? Possibly by finding out what is set as a default application for a file extension and then attempt to maximize it? Are there better approaches?

Comment: I would suggest you minimize your Java application.

Comment: I attempted doing that, as described in the question.